# KeyError: 'bpy_prop_collection[key]: key "Specular" not found'

Tags: modeling, python, development

I'm kind of new on this. I just want to do simple stuff to develop MLOs YMAPs for RDR2 and RedM community. I installed this add-on to manage the assets but 95% of the time I'm having issues with the same KeyError. Link to the add-on: https://github.com/Ktos93/Sollumz_rdr3

> Error importing:
> C:\Users\juano\OneDrive\Desktop\Proyecto_Prueba\new_com3_837royal.ydr.xml
> Traceback (most recent call last):
>
> File "C:\Users\juano\AppData\Roaming\Blender
> Foundation\Blender\4.0\scripts\addons\Sollumz_rdr3-main\sollumz_operators.py",
> line 65, in import_file
> import_ydr(filepath, self.import_settings)
>
> File "C:\Users\juano\AppData\Roaming\Blender
> Foundation\Blender\4.0\scripts\addons\Sollumz_rdr3-main\ydr\ydrimport.py",
> line 624, in import_ydr
> drawable = drawable_to_obj(ydr_xml, filepath, os.path.basename(
>
> File "C:\Users\juano\AppData\Roaming\Blender
> Foundation\Blender\4.0\scripts\addons\Sollumz_rdr3-main\ydr\ydrimport.py",
> line 540, in drawable_to_obj
> materials = shadergroup_to_materials(drawable.shader_group, filepath)
>
> File "C:\Users\juano\AppData\Roaming\Blender
> Foundation\Blender\4.0\scripts\addons\Sollumz_rdr3-main\ydr\ydrimport.py",
> line 21, in shadergroup_to_materials
> material = create_shader(shader.name, shader.filename)
>
> File "C:\Users\juano\AppData\Roaming\Blender
> Foundation\Blender\4.0\scripts\addons\Sollumz_rdr3-main\ydr\shader_materials.py",
> line 734, in create_shader
> create_basic_shader_nodes(mat, shader, filename)
>
> File "C:\Users\juano\AppData\Roaming\Blender
> Foundation\Blender\4.0\scripts\addons\Sollumz_rdr3-main\ydr\shader_materials.py",
> line 592, in create_basic_shader_nodes
> link_specular(node_tree, spectex)
>
> File "C:\Users\juano\AppData\Roaming\Blender
> Foundation\Blender\4.0\scripts\addons\Sollumz_rdr3-main\ydr\shader_materials.py",
> line 345, in link_specular
> links.new(spctex.outputs["Color"], bsdf.inputs["Specular"])
>
> KeyError: 'bpy_prop_collection[key]: key "Specular" not found'

Answer (score 1):

A more general answer than [unwave's](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/314748/65455):

You're probably using a script that was intended for an older version of Blender (or vice versa, but I'll assume you downloaded the latest version of Blender, which is 4). You can try to find or wait for an updated script, or download the Blender version the script was written for from [here](https://download.blender.org/release/).

On the Github page of the script you link to it mentions requiring "*Blender 2.8 or later*", but requirements like that usually don't take into account completely new versions.

**I suggest you just download Blender 2.8x from the link above, and try again.**

Comment: It is indeed version 4.0, as indicated in the file paths

Comment: @Gorgious Right, that was actually obvious :)

Answer (score 0):

In Blender 4 `Specular` is renamed internally to `Specular IOR Level`.

https://github.com/blender/blender/blob/09666e149871769b5b77ac8c2a404e3a4ea35f30/source/blender/blenloader/intern/versioning_400.cc#L1271

The addon should be using version dependent string enumerators similar to `enum.StrEnum` instead of string literals. Or version dependent constants in a simple solution.